# How to click on a key/button while it's monitored?

Tags: python, pywin32, pyautogui

For example in Python if I wait for a key to be pressed with pynput,keyboard&mouse modules or win32api I can't click on the same key.

```
import pyautogui 
import win32api 


while True: 

    if win32api.GetKeyState(0x01) < 0: # it doesn't work with 0x01 but if you replace it by 0x02 or any other key it will work and want it to work with 0x01 that's the problem
        pyautogui.PAUSE = 0.1 
        pyautogui.click()
```

0x01 is the left mouse button https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes

I can't do the thing above because I wil click on the same button that is waited to be pressed

Why I can't do that and How I can solve that ? Or find another alternative to do that

EDIT : If I take the example of razer synapse mouses You can click on a key that is monitored

Comment: You can try this code on cookie.riimu.net/speed and yeah it doesn't work, when you press the left button mouse key it will not click with a pause BUT if you to the same thing with 0x02(the right mouse button) instead of 0x01(left mouse button) it will work

Comment: Anyone ????????